# How to add single quotes for string value of dynamic query string and use it in linq

Tags: c#, string, linq

I am passing this following query string in where method using linq. I am using dynamic linq library.

Querystring:

```
(cid=GB)AND(lvl=50 OR lvl=51 OR lvl=52 OR lvl=53 OR lvl=54 OR lvl=55 OR lvl=56 OR lvl=57 OR lvl=58 OR lvl=59 OR lvl=60)
```

Linq Query:

```
var query = context.Tablename.Where(resultQueryString, null);
```

Before passing the query string I have to change the string cid to countrycode and lvl to level . so i used string builder for replacing the string.

```
           StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder(querystring);
           outputString.Replace("cid","CountryCode");
           outputString.Replace("lvl", "Level");
           outputString.Replace("AND", "&&");
           outputString.Replace("OR", "||");
```

here what is my question is i have to add the single quotes for countrycode value ie, i have to get output like (countrycode='GB')&&(level=50 || level=51 || level=52 ...)

how i can add single quotes for countrycode value and pass that querystring into where method.

please provide the solution or any other way we can achieve this one.

Comment: country code will be always 2 characters long or it can be more than 2 characters?

Comment: Where do you get the query string from?

Comment: country code contains 2 characters now.

Comment: actually this query string is a value of one field from table. i am getting this one public List<class> methodname(string[] strQueries)
        {            
           
            foreach (string querystring in strQueries){}
}

Comment: If you've fix structure/pattern then you can do something like this: `outputString.Replace("cid=", "CountryCode='");` and `outputString.Replace(")AND", "')&&");`

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
string outputString = "(cid=GB)AND(lvl=50 OR lvl=51 OR lvl=52 OR lvl=53 OR lvl=54 OR lvl=55 OR lvl=56 OR lvl=57 OR lvl=58 OR lvl=59 OR lvl=60)";
            int lastindex = outputString.IndexOf(")");
            int firstindex = outputString.IndexOf("=");
            outputString = outputString.Substring(0, firstindex+1) + "'" + outputString.Substring(firstindex+1, 2) + "'" + outputString.Substring(lastindex);
```

the output is:
(cid='GB')AND(lvl=50 OR lvl=51 OR lvl=52 OR lvl=53 OR lvl=54 OR lvl=55 OR lvl=56 OR lvl=57 OR lvl=58 OR lvl=59 OR lvl=60)